# notifying the server (XMLHttpRequest?) on the onunload event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, comet, tornado

Is it possible to notify a server (make a single HTTP request with a bit of data, response is unimportant) when client leaves the page?

I'm actually using python-tornado comet application with javascript constantly keeping a request connection to the server (which gets closed and re-opened on event. Based off this: https://launchpad.net/eftw).

I didn't find a easy way to debug this (with FireBug, in particular). That makes it quite problematic.

Oh, and the actual code (since it somewhat usable already anyway): http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~hoverhell/xftw/trunk/files

Comment: Oh. Actually, I didn't do that in most cases because I didn't find any answer really acceptable (or, for few, missed the actual answer). Guess I should lower my perfection preference regarding answers :)

Comment: @hell.orts.ru - That's valid, it's more for the *next* guy to find a working solution (or at least an explanation on why) when they arrive via google :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in a *reliable* way, depending on browser and latency, your XmlHttpRequest is likely to be killed before it actually finishes.

Browser makers want to (correctly, imo) render the next page as quickly as possible.  The `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` are cleanup events meant to quickly dispose of any variables left around, they're not meant to be waited on...so the browser doesn't.  Since garbage collection in newer browsers has also improved significantly, the browser has even less reason to wait on these events.

You can send a request in the `window.onbeforeunload` event...but will it get to the server? Maybe.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to process XHR while in onbeforeunload function/state. Or, at least, it didn't in my case.

Comment: As an extra: is there some way to debug stuff that happens on page close?

Comment: @hell.orts.ru - You could use Firebug and turn "Persist" mode on so it keeps the data when going to the next page, that's usually the best method for me.

Comment: Ah. It's not actually what I expected, because my subj. page does not have any external links. But I can add some for that specifically, so thanks for the idea.

Comment: can someone let me know how to do asynrhonous XHR pls?